# Drawing a Koch snowflake in Android

Tags: java, android, graphics, fractals

Here's my attempt to draw [Koch snowflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake). My initial state is a line instead of an equilateral triangle so that I am able to fit maximum detail in a mobile phone window. 
My thought process was:

- Start with two points A, B separated distance r.
- Draw three points between them, P1, P2, P3.
- P1 at distance r/3 from A on line AB.
- P2 at r/3 from the P1 at 60 degrees from the AB.
- P3 at 2*r/3 from A on line AB.

### Code

```
public class KochView extends View {

    List<PointF> points = new LinkedList<>();
    private int depth = 6;

    public KochView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public KochView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {

        final int H = getHeight();
        final int W = getWidth();

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAlpha((int) (255 * 0.99));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);

        // Adjust start/end points for the Koch 'snowflake' depending on whether we are in
        // portrait...
        if (H > W) {
            points.add(new PointF(0.05f * W, 0.01f * H));
            points.add(new PointF(0.05f * W, 0.99f * H));
        }// or landscape mode...
        else {
            points.add(new PointF(0.01f * W, 0.95f * H));
            points.add(new PointF(0.99f * W, 0.95f * H));
        }

        // The current algo does not draw start and end points, so we draw them manually...
        drawPoint(canvas, paint, points.get(0));
        drawPoint(canvas, paint, points.get(1));

        doPairWise(points, new Action<PointF>() {
            @Override
            public List<PointF> exec(PointF first, PointF second) {

                // Find the distance between the given two points
                double r = dist(first, second);

                // And the angle they subtend w.r.t the x-axis
                float th = (float) (Math.atan2(second.y - first.y, second.x - first.x));

                // Get the first point according the Koch snowflake iteration definition. I.e. at
                // 1/3 rd the distance, on the line joining th two points.
                PointF p1 = getPoint(first, (float) (r / 3), th);
                // Get the second point, at 1/3 distance from the *first* point, at an angle of
                // 60 degrees from the line joining the given points,
                PointF p2 = getPoint(p1, (float) (r / 3), (float) (th - PI / 3));
                // Get the third point, at 2/3 the distance, on the line joining the given points.
                PointF p3 = getPoint(first, (float) (2 * r / 3), th);

                // Draw all three...
                drawPoint(canvas, paint, p1);
                drawPoint(canvas, paint, p2);
                drawPoint(canvas, paint, p3);

                // Add them to a list...
                List<PointF> more = new LinkedList<>();
                more.add(p1);
                more.add(p2);
                more.add(p3);

                // Return the list of points for further iteration
                return more;
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Get a point at radial distance 'r' and a given angle 't' w.r.t a given point.
     *
     * @param src The source point.
     * @param r   The radial distance in pixels.
     * @param t   The angle in radians.
     * @return The new point.
     */
    private PointF getPoint(PointF src, float r, float t) {
        PointF result = new PointF();
        result.x = (int) (src.x + r * Math.cos(t));
        result.y = (int) (src.y + r * Math.sin(t));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Recursively do an action on consecutive pair from a list. Here the action is drawing three
     * more points in between them to plat a Koch snowflake.
     *
     * @param list   The list of items to make the pairs from.
     * @param action The action to do. In this case 'action' should draw the points on the canvas
     *               and return them for calculation of future iterations.
     */
    private void doPairWise(List<PointF> list, Action<PointF> action) {

        // New points are added to this list alongwith existing ones and this is used as the list
        // of points for the next iteration.
        List<PointF> tmp = new LinkedList<>();

        // Depth to terminate the recursion at
        if (--depth <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        int size = list.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i += 1) {
            final List<PointF> more = action.exec(list.get(i), list.get(i + 1));
            // Add the starting point to the list of all points...
            tmp.add(list.get(i));
            // ...add the three points in the iteration of a Koch snowflake.
            tmp.addAll(more);
        }

        // finally add the last point to all points.
        tmp.add(list.get(size - 1));

        // Repeat the above process with the new list and the same "action"
        doPairWise(tmp, action);
    }

    private interface Action<T> {
        /**
         * Do something with a pair of objects. Optionally, return a list of the same type.
         *
         * @param first  First object to do smth with.
         * @param second Second object to smth with.
         * @return Optionally return a list of same type as inputs.
         */
        List<T> exec(T first, T second);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method. to draw a point on a canvas with a give paint.
     *
     * @param canvas The canvas to draw the point on.
     * @param paint  The paint to draw the point with.
     * @param point  The point to draw.
     */
    private static void drawPoint(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, PointF point) {
        canvas.drawPoint(point.x, point.y, paint);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Euclidean distance between two points.
     *
     * @param p1 First point.
     * @param p2 Second point.
     * @return The distance, as the crow flies, between the given points.
     */
    private static double dist(PointF p1, PointF p2) {
        return dist(p1.x, p2.x, p1.y, p2.y);
    }

    private static double dist(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
        return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
    }
}
```

Output:

Depth = 6

[image: Depth = 6]

Depth = 8

[image: Depth = 8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some minor issues, nothing serious...

- Try to calculate the points *before* you draw and store them to easily redraw them (and not calculate over again).
- What's the purpose of the `Action` interface, what does `exec` do? A more suitable name would be really helpful (maybe `IntersectingArea` or `addBranches` - but my english is bad., do snow flakes have branches or arms or... I dont know).
- Additionally why do you use a **generic** `Action<>` interface - it's absouletly bound to be used for `Point`s (or `PointF`) and I do not see any usage in any other types of parameters.
- Maybe you should get away totally from that interface and declare class, because i don't see any other usage for that interface. it's for your implementation only, it's specific for your cause, hence make a *class* (no interface). especially when you read the documentation of the interface: ' do something with a pair of objects ' (???).
- Why do you cast the destination of the translation of a `PointF` into `int` in the method `getPoint()` (and why don't you rename it into `translateRadial`) ... you can still cast it down into `int` when you're **drawing** the point, so cast it down to `float` .
- I do not know why you declare a method `drawPoint()` when there is no difference between the usage in `onDraw()` - make paint and canvas member vairables and change the method into:

### Code:

```
private void drawPoint(PointF p) {
    canvas.drawPoint(point.x, point.y, paint); //canvas is member, paint is member
}
```